# Convert single user from windows classic to windows claims

Tags: migration, claims-based-auth, user-accounts, claims, conversion

3 years ago we migrated from `SP2010` to `SP2013` and so also the users. We noticed that some users have not been migrated/converted. I was looking for a way to convert them and found the [Move-SPUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) cmd-let but i'm not sure if it is the correct way. I've also seen the [Convert-SPWebApplication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219696.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but I need to convert single users, not an entire application.

Which is the right way?

Another doubt: What happens with the `Author` and `Editor` fields of the existing items/documents?

Answer (score 2):

Move-spuser is the good option as all of ur user migrated already.

When you run move-spuser from old accounts to new account then it will update old user everywhere with new.

https://sharepoint.protiviti.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=262

Answer (score 2):

`Convert-SPWebApplication` only converts users that are not claims to claims. There's no issues with converting the entire Web Application again (this is done, for example, if you attach a 'classic' content database to a claims-enabled Web Application after the Web Application was converted to claims). `Convert-SPWebApplication` would be the correct approach here, and not `Move-SPUser`.